# Java.IO.EOFException reading from OkHttpClient via proxy with authorization

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin, okhttp

I'm getting Java.IO.EOFException when try to read data from HttpUrlConnection (when accessing InputStream)
I use xamarin with OkHttp library, the application is run on genymotion emulator with Android 4.2.2

Here is the sample code (C#):

```
    // ...
       var okHttpClient = CreateHttpClient();
       var conn = okHttpClient.Open(new URL(address));
       var inputStream = conn.InputStream; //here is the exception
    // ...

    private OkHttpClient CreateHttpClient()
    {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        client.SetProxy(new Proxy(Proxy.Type.Http, new InetSocketAddress(Host, Port)));
        client.SetAuthenticator(new MyAuthenticator(User, Password));            

        return client;
    }

    private class MyAuthenticator: Java.Lang.Object, IOkAuthenticator
    {
        private readonly string _user;
        private readonly string _password;

        public MyAuthenticator(string user, string password)
        {
            _user = user;
            _password = password;
        }

        public OkAuthenticatorCredential Authenticate(Proxy p0, URL p1, IList<OkAuthenticatorChallenge> p2)
        {
            return OkAuthenticatorCredential.Basic(null, null); //this is never called
        }

        public OkAuthenticatorCredential AuthenticateProxy(Proxy p0, URL p1, IList<OkAuthenticatorChallenge> p2)
        {
            return OkAuthenticatorCredential.Basic(_user, _password);
        }
    }
```

When proxy is without authorization everything works.

When I use .Net mono WebClient, it works with proxy authorization (but I have reasons not to use mono WebClient if possible)

Workaround conn.SetRequestProperty("Connection", "close"); does not help.

Stacktrace:

```
Download Error: Java.IO.EOFException: Exception of type 'Java.IO.EOFException' was thrown.
  at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallObjectMethod (IntPtr jobject, IntPtr jmethod) [0x00063] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.10.1-branch/d23a19bf/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.g.cs:177 
  at Java.Net.URLConnection.get_InputStream () [0x00043] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.10.1-branch/d23a19bf/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-14/src/generated/Java.Net.URLConnection.cs:754 
  at MachiningCloud.AndroidNet.WebClient.DownloadFile (System.String address, System.String fileName) [0x0002c] in c:\Projects\iDPTech\Main\Source\DPTech.ToolSelector.Ios\MachiningCloud.AndroidNet\WebClient.cs:63 
  at UrlImageViewHelper.UrlImageViewHelper.DownloadImageToFile (System.String url, System.String filename) [0x00007] in c:\Projects\iDPTech\Main\Source\DPTech.ToolSelector.Ios\MonoDroid.UrlImageViewHelper.Android\UrlImageViewHelper.cs:387 
  at UrlImageViewHelper.UrlImageViewHelper.RunInBackgroundFunc (UrlImageViewHelper.TaskParams[] taskParams) [0x001c3] in c:\Projects\iDPTech\Main\Source\DPTech.ToolSelector.Ios\MonoDroid.UrlImageViewHelper.Android\UrlImageViewHelper.cs:349 
  --- End of managed exception stack trace ---
java.io.EOFException
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.Util.readAsciiLine(Util.java:342)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.RawHeaders.fromBytes(RawHeaders.java:311)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.makeTunnel(Connection.java:313)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.upgradeToTls(Connection.java:127)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:107)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:294)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:351)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:297)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:180)
    at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:246)
    at urlimageviewhelper.AnonymousAsyncTask_3.n_doInBackground(Native Method)
    at urlimageviewhelper.AnonymousAsyncTask_3.doInBackground(AnonymousAsyncTask_3.java:29)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Nikolay

Comment: Have you tried ModernHttpClient: https://github.com/paulcbetts/ModernHttpClient ?

Comment: @Cheesebaron, in fact, I use OkHttp from installed NuGet package of ModernHttpClient. I don't know how to pass proxy settings to HttpClient or OkHttpNetworkHandler (via headers?), so use OkHttpClient (which is used by OkHttpNetworkHandler as well)

Comment: I have a similar issue. I'm actually using straight HttpURLConnection (which OkHttpClient is also using if you look at your call stack). But what I discovered is this is only happening for HTTS URLs, it works fine with HTTP URLs. @NicolaiShestakov Have you found anything since you posted this in 2014 ?

Answer (score 2):

To use an HTTP proxy to reach an HTTPS URL it needs to build a tunnel. This is failing; the proxy is not creating the tunnel. Have you confirmed that the proxy you're using supports the URL you're trying to reach?

Comment: It works via .NET WebClient class, so it must be OK with the proxy

Comment: Can you capture the wire data with wireshark? It would be interesting to see what your proxy is sending that OkHttp can't handle.

Comment: @JesseWilson I have a similar issue. It works OK with HTTP but not with HTTPS. I am using Fiddler on local machine and I'm using `HttpURLConnection`. I am pretty sure it's not a problem with Fiddler since if I use HttpWebRequest with same proxy and same credentials in a C# console app, it works fine for both HTTP and HTTPS

Answer (score 2):

Saw same error today. my URL string has some spaces. After changed it to %20, issue disappeared.